# Django loop and accessing the objects and dictionary items in template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary, for-loop

So I came across this problem with django templates and I thought the solution might be useful for others:
here I will assume a pretty complicated situation so it also can be used in simpler cases:
let's assume we need to access a list of articles and their id and title in the template. additionally we want to pass some extra data about each article (like publisher) using a dictionary since they are not in the class attributes. what makes it even harder is when you want to access this articles two by two. meaning a for loop iterating over range of 0 to index of last item and being able to access item number i and i+1 at the same time.
this was particularly hard because as you might know if you want to use a dictionary in django template you can't do:

```
{{ publishers[article.id] }}
```

because [] are not supported in the template. no big deal you can treat fields as attributes like

```
{{ publishers.0 }}
```

but django template won't let you do

```
{{ publishers.article.id }}
```

let alone using a for loop and accessing articles through a list and index like :

```
{{ publishers.articles.i.id }}
```

so what do we do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here's the answer.
it's a bit over complicated but I wanted to cover all the possibilities. 
first off we need to be able to access objects of a dictionary by defining our own filter like [this](https://push.cx/2007/django-template-tag-for-dictionary-access):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def hash_dict(h, key):  
   return h[key]

def get_attr(item,field):
   dict_obj = item.__dict__
      return dict_obj[field]

register.filter('hash_dict',hash_dict)
register.filter('get_attr',get_attr)
```

we'll get to the get_attr method in a moment but for now, we can access dictionary objects in the template :

```
{% load modulename %}
{{ dictionary|hash_dict:obj.id }}
```

to have a for loop with counter you can pass a range object or list to the template.

```
range_of_article = range(0, len(articles_list), 2)
```

and somehow pass that variable to the template.
in your template :

```
{% for i in range_of_article %}
   {% with article=articles|hash_dict:i %}
      {% with article_id=article|get_attr:'id' %}
         {{ publishe|hash_dict:article_id }}
```

this is where get_attr method comes in handy. I could have just used article.id with no problems here but sometimes that's not the case. I find this workaround to be very useful when you cant access an attrubute of object with object.attribute won't work.
and finally to have access to i and i+1 at the same time:

```
{% for i in range_of_article %}
   {% with j=i|add:1 %}
      {% with article=articles|hash_dict:i article2=articles|hash_dict:j %}
         {% with article_id=article|get_attr:'id'  article_id2=article2|get_attr:'id'%}
            {{ publishe|hash_dict:article_id }}
            {{ publishe|hash_dict:article_id2 }}
```

Comment: This is really over-complicated. You can just iterate over a list with a simple `for`, and for a dict you can iterate over `.items` to give the key and the value. And you don't need to pass separate values in a dict anyway; you can just annotate them directly on the objects.

Comment: I know it is over-complicated. in my specific case the fact was I couldn't iterate over items or annotate values. the point is to assume most complicated scenario to cover almost everything I learned in the process. I though this might help someone in my position. for most purposes however doing what you mentioned is sufficient.